# How to check if a std::function is set and valid?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, std-function

I have an `std::function` which is being set like below:

```
typedef std::function<void(bool some_state)> TheListener;
void ListenTo(TheListener the_listener) {
    m_the_listener = the_listener;
}
```

How do I check if the `std::function` is set?

```
private:
    void SomePrivateMethod() {
        // How do I check here that m_the_listener is set by calling ListenTo ?
        m_the_listener();
    }
```

Is it enough to check `if (m_the_listener)` before calling `m_the_listener()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool) does state that verifying the `std::function` instance in a condition should be sufficient to verify if it has a valid callable target. So yes, `if (m_the_listener)` should be enough.